# 23 different Arayos Mitzvos for Jews vs one for non-Jews

Tags: gentiles, halacha-theory, arayot

1. Both 613 Jewish and 7 Noahides are called Mitzvos (ז' מצוות בני נוח)
2. We have a separate Mitzvah for every Ervah (one for mother and one for sister etc), for a total of 22 (I think).
3. Non-Jews have one Mitzvah that includes 6 Arayos ([Rambam Milchamot 9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.9?lang=he))

> "שֵׁשׁ עֲרָיוֹת אֲסוּרוֹת עַל בְּנֵי נֹחַ. הָאֵם. וְאֵשֶׁת הָאָב. וְאֵשֶׁת אִישׁ. וַאֲחוֹתוֹ מֵאִמּוֹ. וְזָכוּר. וּבְהֵמָה."

Why in Judaism each one is a separate Mitzvah and for NJ they are just details of one Issur?

Comment: Aren't there also multiple AZ commands for Jews? And multiple Dinim ones? And multiple kinds of stealing?

Comment: למאי נפקא מינה?

Comment: @DoubleAA You have a strange tendency to de-ligitimate questions. I don't care for Dinim, I ask for Arayos. You might want to generalize the question - ask a new one.

Comment: Maybe you have a tendency to ask bad questions. I'm just pointing out the obvious.

Comment: Anyone can generalize this question in situ https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1299/759

Answer (score 3):

Makkos 3:16:

> רַבִּי חֲנַנְיָא בֶּן עֲקַשְׁיָא אוֹמֵר, רָצָה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְזַכּוֹת אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל, לְפִיכָךְ הִרְבָּה לָהֶם תּוֹרָה וּמִצְוֹת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה מב) יְיָ חָפֵץ לְמַעַן צִדְקוֹ יַגְדִּיל תּוֹרָה וְיַאְדִּיר:
>
> R’ Chananya Ben Akashia says: Hashem wanted to give merit to Israel, therefore he increased for them Torah and Mitzvos, as it says, “Hashem wanted for the sake of His righteousness, He increased Torah and glorified it.”

As this concern only exists for Jews, our Mitzvos are split into many; for the non-Jews, one is sufficient.